# "not executable: magic 7F45" when running redsocks on Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, proxy, compatibility, genymotion

I'm trying to get [ProxyDroid](https://github.com/madeye/proxydroid) or [redsocks](https://github.com/darkk/redsocks) to run on the Genymotion Android emulator (x86). ADB shell into the device, run redsocks and I get `not executable: magic 7F45`.

I know it means that the version doesn't comply with the CPU. However, on Genymotion, I'm able to run a bunch of ARM packages with no problem (having installed the Genymotion ARM translation files).

I have compiled redsocks sources on my Ubuntu box (binary works fine on my Ubuntu x86), but when I copied the binary to the emulator, it still gives the same error message when I try to run it (`not executable: magic 7F45`). So, it looks like neither the ARM nor the x86 versions are working on the emulator.

I also have taken the redsocks binary that I compiled on my Ubuntu x86 box and pushed it to x86 AVD (standard SDK) - it worked perfectly. So it appears that the `not executable: magic 7F45` error is not related to the cross-CPU compilation?

Is there a way to get redsocks run on Genymotion?

Answer (score 1):

What `file(1)` utility says about your compiled binary?

Because compiling on x86-based PC does not promises your binary always will have x86 target platform - GCC can produce virtually any targets.

Answer (score 1):

You can't freely copy binaries from your Ubuntu box to emulator one - even if all are x86-based, they use different basic OS libraries.

To compile binary for Android-x86 target you must use special cross-compiling tools\environment. See Android sources toolchain to take a look on how they configure gcc+ld switches to create *android-x86* binaries on Ubuntu box.